# Powerballs are real training tool?

Tags: training, hands

I started to go to fencing few weeks ago and got myself a powerball to strengthen my wrist. But even if after you use until you can feel in your arms that you made an effort, I didn't notice many improvements and a complete lack of stiffness. I guess because it forces you to have your arm in a fixed position with a weight, and also having your wrist moving you feel like you are doing a lot of exercise but really you are not doing much.

The other side of a powerball is it use as a toy. Its funny to see how long it takes your friend to make it work and after that compete to see who can make it spin faster.

That made me think that it more a toy that a training tool.

I am right or I am not using it correctly?

Comment: Powerballs are good training tools to reinforce extremely weak muscles, as forearm muscles after having broken a bone. In these cases (I have experienced it in my calves) muscles are so weak they cannot afford any staightforward training routine and need tools as easy weights or electro-stimulation

Answer (score 6):

Ah, the powerball. I had forgotten these existed after I broke mine.

A powerball is indeed a workout tool, but it has an extremely limited effect. It can help with strengthening grip by engaging forearm muscles, but depending on how you "swing" it, you can get some upper arm and shoulder work into it.

**Forearms**

To train forearm and grip, have a constant 90 degree angle in your elbow joint, and simply rotate your wrist to keep it going.

**Upper arms**

This time, keep your wrist fixed, and rotate your elbow joint to keep it going. This engages the bicep and tricep, and will take a bit of getting used to. But again, it's very import that you're not rotating your wrist here. It should be completely straight throughout the entire movement, and the only joint that is moving is the elbow.

**Shoulders**

This is the tricky one. Extend your arm completely out to the side, and lock out both your elbow and wrist. Now rotate the entire arm to keep the ball in motion. It's kinda like washing your window, but with a completely straight arm. Your hand should be making perfect circular motions.

---

It's important to note that the powerball is not a wholesome training apparatus. It's not so much a tool for getting stronger, but just to get the blood flowing, and prevent stiffness from prolonged periods of little to no activity.

Answer (score 1):

It is a training tool, it's just not the ultimate tool that the website claims it to be.

I've used it mostly for work on grip strength and forearm stabilization. Use it at a high speed, with a wide fingered grip to promote the grip strength, and rotate the forearm around the "axis". Also you can flex/extend the wrist to work on the forearm.

I've used it to increase grip strength for sword form competitions, and it's a minor tool but it can be useful.

Comment: Agreed. I don't know why anyone would advertise it as an "ultimate" anything.